# Can't stop re-render for color background with useMemo React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

On each re-render it generates a new color. How do I cache the first color it gets initialized and re-use it each now?

```
  const backgroundColor = newBackgroundColor(); // some random color

  const background = React.useMemo(() => {
    return backgroundColor;
  }, []);

  const buttonStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
          background: background,
  };

  return (
    <button style={buttonStyle}>
  )
```

Comment: you  can just use a ref to store the color

Answer (score 4):

```
  const background = React.useMemo(() => {
    return newBackgroundColor(); // some random color
  }, [newBackgroundColor]);

  const buttonStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
          background: background,
  };

  return (
    <button style={buttonStyle}>
  )
```